# How can I make my website's background image (wallpaper/skin) clickable?

Tags: html, frontend

I am trying to make the background/skin/wallpaper of my site http://www.outpostmagazine.com/ clickable so that when a user click the background they are sent to another site.

Comment: A useful trick : http://ran.ge/2009/11/11/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Comment: Thanks for this Elizion! I gave it a shot but it seems to be placing the image and link in the wrong spot: http://outpost.rgenta.com/

Comment: Do you mean you want the whole top banner to be clickable, and currently only the top left corner of it is clickable?

Comment: I want both the left and right side of the background/wallpaper/skin to be clickable. Please see this image as an illustration of what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/OF4BRPn.png

Answer (score 0):

When I open your page, the left and right images you wish to make clickable are not even visible. From the little I can see of them, it appears that you have overlapping elements. I would suggest you take a look  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)  to ensure you have correct positioning of your elements, and then attempt to make your images clickable. If you are still having issues, post your relevant scripting.